# Text Parser to XML

Tags: xml, parsing, text

Guys, I'm able to parse the file right now. I need some assistance that how can i make a Hashmap/Hashtable from the output. 
For example 
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Rangarajkarthik
FN:karthik Rangaraj
EMAIL:kart2006@gmail.com
EMAIL:karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com
END:VCARD

From the above sample output, how can i make an id for the name and store those email address corresponding to the name.
Ideas and Help will be highly appreciated. Thank u guys.

Comment: By "parse this file as a XML file" do you really mean "parse this file and write out the data in an XML format"?  If this is the case you will need to define how you want the XML to look.  It would be easiest to write a simple converter in a scripting language such as Python or Perl.  If you can use an XSLT 2 processor (i.e. Saxon) then you could do this completely in XSLT using unparsed entities.

Comment: Hi Jim, could you give me some examples link for text to xml conversion. Thanks.

Comment: can any one help me with this :java-forums.org/new-java/44727-parse-part-file-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java, for instance, you may use `String` methods to parse .part file (`line.split(":")`) and [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) framework for creating xml file.

Comment: Hi, is there any other method available?

Comment: Hm... For parsing input file you may use regilar expressions, but... String methods for this problems are easier to use. For generating output xml you may try [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html). Have a look at [Programming XML in Java, Part 1](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-03-xmlsax.html?page=1)

Comment: can any one help me with this :http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/44727-parse-part-file-2.html